# Disk Cleanup, won't delete?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I am desperately trying to free up space on my SSD. I ran disk cleanup as admin and saw this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ibin.co](https://ibin.co/3KRQQNqHR1N9.png))</sub>

So I ran that, and then looked at disc space, and it only free'd up less than 1GB.

Whats going on?

Comment: And if i run disk cleanup again, it shows that there's no space to be freed up.

Comment: Rather than commenting on your own post, edit it to add this additional information to it. Have you rebooted your computer since running the cleanup? What else is occurring on your computer? Are you running low on space?

Comment: I ran into this exact issue earlier on today, with very similar results.  When I reran Disk Cleanup as administrator I got different results (it still did not free up the 9.5 gigs Windows has stolen).

Comment: Show us Event Manager, which is where, Windows error reporting data would be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you can try for troubleshooting:

Method 1:

Try running the Check Disk and see if it helps:
Check the drive for errors.

- Open command prompt (as admin) and run `chkdsk /f`

Method 2:

If the issue still persists, try performing SFC (System File Checker) scan on your computer and check if it helps.

- Open command prompt as admin a run `sfc /scannow` to correct some inconsistencies in file system.

Method 3:

Try performing the Disk cleanup in Safe Mode and see if it helps
Start your computer in safe mode

Method 4.

Perform a clean boot.

- Remove AC power and battery, then press and hold power button for approx 30 seconds. This drains all the current in the circuit and resets some memory modules to a fresh state

Method 5.

Run maintenance troubleshooter

- Go to control panel and select troubleshooting, choose the maintenance troubleshooter to diagnose and correct problems.

Recheck if issue is resolved

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

When a hardware or software problem occurs on your computer, Windows  collects information that describes the problem, called a problem report. Report details can include the name of a program that has stopped working, the date and time that a problem occurred.

Are you using any registry cleaning apps.

It could be caused by some registry cleaning program that was allowed to delete or delete part of these registry entries located at:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches

Use windows defragmenter and then use disk cleanup

Comment: Are you asking questions here or writing answer?